# Recover Data from a crashed process (with .dmp file)

Tags: windows-7, crash, process, dump

I made a .dmp file of my process that crashed.
It contained very important data.

How will I recover that data. The process had it sat in ram, then hung half-way through saving. I made a 'Dump File' with task manager, but how do I restore the data from it?

Comment: Is this an application you have the source code for, or at least source symbols?  Do you know if the process is a native executable or a .NET process?  Process dumps are typically used for debugging application crashes, and while the data you're looking for is probably in there, it may not be easy to find it.

Comment: @heavyd Unfortunately not. The program is 'Screen Vidshot' and it contains very Important photos. It was taking a photo every 10th of a second, through my laptop's webcam. If I can't get those back, it wouldn't be very easy, though it would be possible, to take it again.

Comment: http://www.geovid.com/screen_vidshot

Comment: Is it worth it, or should I just re-film it?

Comment: From the quick look at that program, it looks like it is probably storing images on disk, not in memory, so the dump may not have the images you're looking for unless they were recent enough they weren't written to disk yet.  I would try to find out where they're being written to disk ([ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) may help) and look there.

Comment: OK, I don't want to load up another instance of the program, lest it over-writes the data, preventing recovery, so I will just let recovery alone and re-film it. It turned out, when I looked back at what I had been doing, I had made a small mistake anyway. So I'll re-film it. Thank you very much for your time though, It's greatly appreciated